# C# Regex Error Unterminated [] set

Tags: c#

I'm receiving this error (I'm using C#):

> parsing "(--[[.*?]])|(--[[.*)" - Unterminated [] set.

When trying to add Lua's multiple comment code. Here is what it should be:

```
--[[
  Hello
]]
```

However, when I take out the ']]' at the end of this Regex:

```
(--[[.*?]])|(--[[.*)
```

it will give me this error. However, if I add the ']]' in the above, example:

```
(--[[.*?]])|(--[[.*]])
```

it works perfectly fine.

Here is the full code:

```
Regex CustomCommentRegex1, CustomCommentRegex2, CustomCommentRegex3;
CustomCommentRegex1 = new Regex(@"--.*$", RegexOptions.Multiline | RegexCompiledOption);
CustomCommentRegex2 = new Regex(@"(--[[.*?]])|(--[[.*)", RegexOptions.Singleline | RegexCompiledOption);
CustomCommentRegex3 = new Regex(@"(--[[.*?]])|(.*]])", RegexOptions.Singleline | RegexOptions.RightToLeft | RegexCompiledOption);
```

'CustomCommentRegex2' is where I get this 'Unterminated [] set' error. I have an issue if I add the ']]' at the end of 'CustomCommentRegex2'. It will highlight the text above '--[[ ]]' the comments and inside of it; anyway, the issue is this 'Unterminated [] set' error.

Comment: escape the brackets.  they are reserved.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the [Regex](http://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html) website

> Because we want to do more than simply search for literal pieces of
>   text, we need to reserve certain characters for special use. In the
>   regex flavors discussed in this tutorial, **there are 11 characters with
>   special meanings: *the opening square bracket [***, the backslash \, the
>   caret ^, the dollar sign $, the period or dot ., the vertical bar or
>   pipe symbol |, the question mark ?, the asterisk or star *, the plus
>   sign +, the opening round bracket ( and the closing round bracket ).
>   These special characters are often called "metacharacters".

Escape the brackets with a \

```
(--\[\[.*?]])|(--\[\[.*)
```

Comment: Note, most regular expression flavors treat the brace { as a literal character, unless it is part of a repetition operator like a{1,3}. So you generally do not need to escape it with a backslash, though you can do so if you want.